# how to override _default manager used by ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Given below snippet,

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
   def create(**kwargs):
       super().create(external_id='xyz', **kwargs)

class Person(models.Model):
   internal_id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
   f_name=models.CharField(db_column='f_name', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
   external_id = models.CharField(db_column='ext_id', null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
   objects = models.Manager()
   custom = CustomManager()


class PersonSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model=Person
     fields='__all__'
```

Here, when .save() method gets called on the serializer,  the default manager used by the the `create` function in serializer is `objects`. I would like this to be changed to `custom` so that when `save` call happens, `create` function inside `CustomManager` gets invoked.

I can achieve this by overriding the super class method `create` in the serializer. But is there any better workaround for this without overriding base class method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look serializer's `save` method it will call either `create` or `update` for your request. Actually, you have two way to achieve this. First, override serializer `create` method;

```
# serializers.py

class PersonSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model = Person
     fields = "__all__"
   
   def create(self, validated_data):
       # create an instance with your custom code and return it
       return instance
```

**off subject:** do not use `"__all__"`, mostly it's not recommended. explicitly specify your fields.

And secondly, you can set your custom manager as default manager with `default_manager_name`. It might be helpful; [`Model.Meta.default_manager_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/managers/#default-managers). The default value for `default_manager_name` is `objects`.

```
# managers.py

from django.db import models


class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        # your logic here
        return obj
```

---

```
# models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    internal_id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    f_name=models.CharField(db_column='f_name', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    external_id = models.CharField(db_column='ext_id', null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)

    objects = models.Manager()
    custom = CustomManager()
    
    class Meta:
        default_manager_name = "custom"
```

But be careful because this method will be work only if you use create method like serializers do; `Person._default_manager.create(**kwargs)`.

Lastly, you need to run Django's `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.